# Online Web Scraper

Tags: android, web-services, web-scraping

I am writing an online web-scraper for an android application that gets data from IMDB related to movies.

My question is a very logical question, the issue is that, we assume that in future 100 copies of the application will be installed by different users who will not update the application. We  also know that IMDB will likely change its web structure at some point. That will require re-writing the scraper already installed on devices.

How can I make sure that the new code will automatically be synchronized with the applications installed in different Android phones already?

Comment: Create a server backend for scraping and call this service from within your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a simplest solution.

Make your web **scraper** and host in onto your web server. then make a web service and call that web service in your application, lets say that IMDB changes its structure, then you would not require to change the structure of the code, you will only make changes in the code of web service and it will be done